# Named queries with PostgreSQL and NHibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, named-query

I'm wrestling with NHibernate named query and PostgreSQL but can't get it to work. I have a function in PostgreSQL database:

```
create or replace function x(results refcursor, id_ bigint)
  returns refcursor
  as
  $$
begin
  open results for
select
    id,
    name,
    number
from
    table_name
where
    id = id_;

    return results;
end;
  $$ language plpgsql;
```

Then I made a mapping in NHibernate:

```
<sql-query name="SqlQueryForTesting">
    <return-scalar column="id" type="long" />
    <return-scalar column="name" type="string" />
    <return-scalar column="number" type="string" />
    <![CDATA[
      begin;
      select x('table_name_cursor', :id);
      fetch all in table_name_cursor;
      commit;
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
```

And finally made a method that calls this named query.

```
public IList MethodForNamedQuery(int id)
        {
            var query = Session.GetNamedQuery("SqlQueryForTesting");
            query.SetInt32("id", id);
            return query.List();
        }
```

The problem is that this code gives me an error.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Field not found
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlRowDescription.FieldIndex(String fieldName)
   at NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.Extract(Object[] data, IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ResultRowProcessor.BuildResultRow(Object[] data, IDataReader resultSet, Boolean hasTransformer, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.GetResultColumnOrRow(Object[] row, IResultTransformer resultTransformer, IDataReader rs, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException
could not execute query
[ begin;
      select x('table_name_cursor', :p0);
      fetch all in table_name_cursor;
      commit; ]
  Name:id - Value:2
```

If I run my query through pgAdmin it works perfectly and returns me one row. So I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in mapping. Can anybody say what is wrong with my mapping?

Comment: Why are you adding `begin` / `commit`?

Comment: I've tried without begin and commit also. Error is still the same.

Comment: were you able to get a resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate doesn't know it's a native query, so it's trying to interpret it like a regular NHibernate query, which would search by mapped entities.

If you could create your function as a stored procedure, you would be able to define your named query like [this example](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#sp_query):

```
<sql-query name="selectAllEmployments_SP">
    <return alias="emp" class="Employment">
        <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
        <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
        <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
        <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
        <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
        <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
        <return-property name="salary">
            <return-column name="VALUE"/>
            <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
        </return-property>
    </return>
    exec selectAllEmployments
</sql-query>
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have stored procedures

Comment: @evilone  I see. But it's not that hard to invoke a function like if it was a stored procedure, right?

Comment: According to this http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure I need fetch results from cursor and no other way is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `id` is meant to be an input parameter, but in your query it was declared as output parameter using `return-scalar`. Try to change it to `query-param` to see if it's working:

```
<query-param column="id" type="long" />
```

Comment: Actually correct is `<query-param name="id" type="long" />`. But my function returns also ID and that's not the case. I set function parameter in code.

Comment: I think that is the problem. Can you just introduce the ID input parameter as a new parameter?